# Added some meta data fields to my table and my grouping sets statement isn't working correctly now

Tags: sql, sql-server

This table should have about 16 rows with a summary row which is achieved through the grouping set statement. I had to add the ReportDate and RowID columns to the table and now the script wont run. I added RowID and ReportDate in the Grouping set, but the output was wrong nd was 490 rows. How would I preserve the function of the grouping sets statement with the addition of the two columns?

```
SELECT DISTINCT GETDATE() AS RefreshDate,
                row_number() over (order by RowID) RowID,
                ReportDate,
                NaicsID AS [NAICS Code],
                iif(NaicsName IS NULL, 'Total', NaicsName) AS Industry,
                FORMAT(SUM(RemainingTerm * BaseRent)/SUM(BaseRent), 'N1') AS [Weighted Average Duration],
                FORMAT(SUM(BaseRent), 'C0') AS [Occupied Contract Rent],
                FORMAT(SUM(BaseRent)/(SELECT SUM(BaseRent) FROM dbo.LeaseData WHERE NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL), 'P1') AS [% of Commercial Total Rent],
                FORMAT(SUM(SpaceLeaseArea), 'N0') AS [Occupied SF],
                FORMAT(SUM(SpaceLeaseArea)/(SELECT SUM(SpaceLeaseArea) FROM dbo.LeaseData WHERE NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL), 'P1') AS [% of Commercial Total SF]

INTO industryExposure
    
FROM [dbo].[LeaseData]
WHERE NaicsID NOT LIKE '%[Legacy Lease]%' AND NextSpaceLeaseID IS NULL
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((NaicsID, NaicsName),());
```

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and uneeded overhead.n

Comment: @Larnu I removed the distinct and added rowID and ReportDate into the grouping set and its giving me the same 490 rows.

Comment: That was my point.

Comment: any non-aggregated column must appear in a grouping set( the same way as NaicsID&Name appear in the first set)..if you would like to aggregate per ReportDate, NaicsID,..Name then add the date in the grouping set `…SETS((ReportDate, NaicsID, NaicsName),())`

Comment: @lptr that worked thanks!